# The method onReceivedError(WebView, int, String, String) is undefined for the type WebChromeClient

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

The method onReceivedError(WebView, int, String, String) is undefined for the type 
 WebChromeClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's because it's defined on `WebViewClient`, not `WebChromeClient`. [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView), int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)